# Select users that have n roles for reporting functions SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an application that uses a standard Role, User and UserRoleJoin architecture.

The application needs to send reports to users based on what group of roles they may be in. For example

**Role**:

```
ID Name
1  Lead
2  Mech
3  Elec
4  Auditor
5  Assigner
```

**UserRole**:

```
UserID RoleID
1       1
1       2
1       4
2       1
2       4
```

I want to be able to send one report to all users that are Leads, Mech and Auditors or a different report to all users that are leads and auditors.

The first report would only be sent to user 1 while the second report would be sent to user 2

Should I have a different table that handle roles to reports associations or should I deal with these groups by a select query?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways.  I would be inclined to use `group by` and `having`:

```
select ur.UserId
from UserRole ur join
     Role r
     on ur.RoleID = r.Id
where name in ('Leads', 'Mech', 'Auditors')
group by ur.UserId
having count(*) = 3;
```

The advantage of this approach is that the logic is all in the `having` clause.  You can make it more flexible, such as all Leads and Mechs who are not Auditors.

Answer (score 1):

If those groups are stable enough they deserve a way to persist them in the DB, kind of `Group(ID PK, Name)`, `RoleGroup(GroupID , RoleID)`

```
declare @grpName varchar(50) = 'my_group';

select ur.UserId
from UserRole ur 
join RoleGroup rg on rg.RoleID = ur.RoleID 
join Group g on rg.GroupID = g.ID and g.Name = @grpName
group by ur.UserId
having count(*) = (select count(*) n 
                   from RoleGroup rg  
                   join Group g on rg.GroupId = g.ID and g.Name = @grpName);
```